# How to pass arguments in SPIM CLI's interactive debugging mode?

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I know that we can do this to pass `arg_inp_file.bin` as an arg to the MIPS program:

`spim -file myfile.s arg_inp_file.bin`

But this loads the argument and starts executing right away.

**How can I achieve the same, using the interactive mode**, like after I add a few breakpoints etc.?